# Querying with nullable dates entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-5

I am trying to run the following against entity framework but am getting an error about  `GetValueOrDefault()`

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var list = context.MemberGroupPermissions
                  .Where(m => m.Date.GetValueOrDefault().Date == today.Date);
```

How do I compare 2 dates where one is nullable?

Comment: what error are u getting there? also what you want should happen if one of them is null?

Answer (score 0):

For the nullable part of the issue, you can just check first that there is a value, and if so do the comparison.

But then it will complain about using the `Date` property, for which you can use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;

var holding =
    context.AVRHoldings
            .Where(x => x.ExpirationDate.HasValue && x.ExpirationDate.Value == date)
            .FirstOrDefault();

Assert.IsNotNull(holding);

holding =
    context.AVRHoldings
            .Where(x => 
                 x.ExpirationDate.HasValue && 
                 EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ExpirationDate.Value) == date.Date)
            .FirstOrDefault();

Assert.IsNotNull(holding);
```